# Lookup from another list - Advanced Workflow SharePoint designer 2013 [out of the box]

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow2013

I am facing problem getting data from another list. Can anyone guide me.
Well I have 3 list name for my inventorysystem.
**1)Product Type
2)Stocks
3)Store Request**

**Product Type** : Product Name (Single Line Text)

**Stock** : Product Name(Lookup from Product Type), Quantity Purchased(Number), Quantity Used(Number), Remaining Stock(Calculation based on other column-Number).

**Store Request** : Items (Lookup from Product Type), Qty(Number)

Variable VStrchk is number

2013 Workflow is in Store request

Well my problem is in workflow. I want to check the stock availability. And if found request qty is larger then remaining stock, then email storekeeper. But Variable VStrchk throw zero.

Kindly suggest what is wrong in my below workflow.  Any help would be great
[![Condition Check][1]][1]

[image: Lookup Check]

Stage: stock Check
Set Variable: VStrchk to Stock:Remaining Stock
if CurrentItem:Qty is greater than Variable: VStrchk
Email: CurrentItem:

Field Data to Retrive
Data Soruce: Stock
Field from Source: Remaining Stock
Return field as: As Double
Fild the list item
Field: ID
Value: Current Items: Items

lookup for integer
Data source: Current Item
Field from source: Items
Return field as: Lookup ID(as integer)

**Edit:

I even tried where product name = Items; but still same result ZERO. Any expert there who can throw lights on this issues.**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is resolved: I created new sub-site and start whole process from zero.
workflow logic is same what i posted in 1st. It's really amazing.. Hope later it won't create similar problem again.  Thank you!